# How to fix this error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object?

Tags: codeigniter

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in 
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Paging\application\models\name_model.php
>   Severity: Error
>   Message: Call to a member function get() on a non-object
>   Filename: models/name_model.php
>   Line Number: 13
>   Backtrace:

**models/name_model.php:**

```
class Name_model extends CI_Model {


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_name()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('name');
        return $query->result();
    }


}
```

Line 13:  $query = $this->db->get('name');

How to fix the error message?

Comment: It's not a form but it capture data that I input manually from phpmyadmin which is 15 names.

Comment: your table name is **name** right?

Comment: The error message means that $this->db is not defined - try and fix that first

Answer (score 1):

You didn't load database libraries that why you getting this error.

Open your autoload.php file and add this string in libraries

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

And another way is you need to load libraries in the model

```
class Name_model extends CI_Model {


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_name()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('name');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly write it as follow when your going to fetch only name(s) from your table,

```
public function get_name()
{
  $query = $this->db->select('name')->get('your_table_name');
  return $query->result();
}
```

It will work fine.